# Nx React - Proxy not working with Nx and React

Tags: reactjs, proxy, cors, nrwl-nx

I have a React application created using Nx and there I'm trying to make api calls to my dev server but getting CORS issues. So I tried setting up a proxy following this link: https://nx.dev/l/r/tutorial/06-proxy#react-nx-tutorial---step-6-proxy-configuration

Inside my project's server, I've added:

workspace.json or project.json

```
"serve": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/web:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "buildTarget": "my-app:build",
        "hmr": true,
        "proxyConfig": "apps/my-app/proxy.conf.json"
      },
```

And proxy.conf.json:

```
{
  "/my-context-path/api/v1": {
    "target": "https://my-dev-server.com",
    "secure": true
  }
}
```

And making api call as:

```
export async function getInfo(planId, nbr) {
   return  await fetch(`/my-context-path/api/v1/getInfo?planId=${planId}&nbr=${nbr}`, {
     method: 'GET',
     headers: {
       'Authorization': 'Basic authHeader',
       'Content-Type': 'text/plain',// adding or removing this header is making no difference
     }
   }).then(async (response) => {
      // success block
   }).catch(async (error) => {
     // failure block
   })
}
```

The issue is that when I set up proxy, I'm getting 404 not found error. And if I directly hit the server without using proxy, I'm getting CORS issue.

[image]

Url being called is: https://localhost:4200/my-context-path/api/v1/getInfo?planId=<...data>&irsNbr=<...data>

Note: Cors has already been enabled in the backend server.

Can someone help me fix this issue or point out what I am missing or doing wrong?

**UPDATE** : Found a solution!
I added "changeOrigin": true in my proxy.conf.json and restarted my system then it started to work fine. But I still don't understand why restarting the system made it work. May be some sort of cache issue, which I'm still not clear about.

proxy.conf.json - updated

```
{
  "/my-context-path/api/v1": {
    "target": "https://my-dev-server.com",
    "secure": true,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Encountered the same issue, restarting the system does indeed work.

Comment: When you say restarting the system, do you mean your whole computer?